Discontinuing my Master's Thesis
Recently, I was planning on finishing my Master's studies and following it up with a PhD.
I received an offer from my advisor last year about this and even already signed up for the
PhD program which would require me to finish my Master's thesis first, which I am technically currently
working on.
After the first semester of my Master's program at my institution, I actually felt very dissatisfied with
the content and quality of the program and did not really learn the things I wanted to (not to say that everything was in vain).
Frankly, I did not really think about the program's content too much in advance but rather blindly continued to study where I
also did my undergraduate degree, out of convenience. I then looked for different institutions but was intrigued by the PhD offer and
discarded the idea of going somewhere else.
Right now, I am kind of at the same point again where, additionally, I am working on a thesis that is not
all that interesting to me and has a very vague / too unspecific topic, in my opinion. I could finish this somehow
but I would certainly not be satisfied with it in an academic sense. The thesis also feels very rushed because it would have to be done in
time for the PhD program to directly follow up.
I thought about it and would like to start a new Master's program somewhere else without finishing my degree at my current institution.
I also want to move to a different country for this and it seems like a good time in my life for doing so.
I talked about all this to my advisor and they want me to definitely at least finish my thesis, since they think
that otherwise my time would be wasted. They said I could also chose a new topic and finish in a year or so. The only thing that
mattered to them was that I would get the degree right now. I do not feel this way at all, as I do not really want to finish it just "because". The question is if it is really such a bad idea to just quit my Master's right now? Would it hurt
my ability to get admission to a new institution? I would appreciate some other views on this.

Consider that in the future, you will be competing against tons of people who did not quit their masters.

What part of the world are you in?

@cag51 Western Europe

You seem to be substituting short term thinking for long term. If you finish the masters you will have more options and people will look at you more positively (many factors) than if you quit.
There is no reason you can't explore other doctoral programs, even abroad, while you finish. If you want an academic career, the nature of your masters is much less important than that you have it, and much less important than success in the doctoral program.
I have to agree with your advisor, that your own best path is to get it finished. I'd suggest otherwise if the advisor was subverting your progress, but it seems the opposite. There are no guarantees if you switch programs. The grass isn't always greener on the other side of the fence.

Thank you. I am still undecided, but I have heard different opinions and arguments and am now more willing to find a compromise. I will definitely be mindful not to fall into the "greener grass" hole.
